# How to get button itself in action closure with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Is possible to get button itself in action closure with SwiftUI ?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("test") {
            // change the color of button when user is tapping on it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the properties of your button you can create a custom `ButtonStyle`.

Use its `configuration` to set the desired behaviour.

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .orange]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
            .cornerRadius(40)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.9 : 1)
    }
}
```

The above example was taken from here: [SwiftUI Tip: ButtonStyle and Animated Buttons](https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-button-style-animation/)

In your case you can adapt it to set a custom background:

```
.background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.red : Color.blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var color = Color.red
    var body: some View {
        Button("test") {
            self.color = Color.green
        }.background(color)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya... I just figure out by myself too

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonColor: Color = Color.clear
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.buttonColor = Color(red: Double.random(in: 0...1),
                                     green: Double.random(in: 0...1),
                                     blue: Double.random(in: 0...1))
        }, label: {
            Text("Button").background(buttonColor)
        })
    }
}
```